# In Game of Thrones, is there evidence of magic involved with the Faith of the Seven?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In Game of Thrones we see evidence that various religions are able to perform magic.  The followers of the Red God are able to give birth to living shadows and bring people back from the dead.  The religion of the Old Gods is founded on magical "Children" and their all-seeing Godswood trees.  Is there any evidence that the Faith of the Seven was founded on supernatural events?  Or is there any evidence that followers have any magical abilities themselves?

Answer (score 4):

No, not really.

There's that wreath thing that Catelyn Stark makes while caring for Bran after his fall, but I'd classify that under a prayer/meditation focus than any sort of actual magic.

Comment: Which makes you wonder why so many people follow the one religion with no associated magic.

Comment: @Torisuda Well, the fact that the Old Gods and R'hllor come "batteries included" isn't broadly known in-universe. You could just as well ask why so many people follow the Catholic church ([which was actually used as the base for the Faith of the Seven](http://www.maximumfun.org/sound-young-america/george-r-r-martin-author-song-ice-and-fire-series-interview-sound-young-america)).

Comment: IIRC, the it's mentioned that the Maesters have been actively engaged with stamping out magic. Are they allied with the Faith of the Seven?